# String replacement with gsub in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

I have the R
I have the following problem and would like to ask for some suggestions and help.

I have this dataframe:

### Dataframe

```
if (!file.exists("storm")){
      dir.create("storm")} fileurl<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2"
download.file(fileurl,destfile = "storm.csv",method = "auto")
storm1<-read.table("storm.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

### Extraction of variables needed

```
storm1[,c("EVTYPE","FATALITIES","INJURIES","PROPDMG","PROPDMGEXP","CROPDMG","CROPDMGEXP")]
```

### Attempt

I want to tidy up the variables because the dataset has all kinds of names and I will just give an example so you guys can check my problem.

WINTER STORM is the string that I want for all this names

```
storm1<-storm1[,EVTYPE:= sapply(EVTYPE,gsub,pattern="^WINTER STORM$|^WINTER STORM/HIGH WINDS$|^WINTER STORM HIGH WINDS$|^WINTER STORM/HIGH WIND$|^HEAVY SNOW/WINTER STORM$|^BLIZZARD/WINTER STORM$|^WINTER STORMS$","WINTER STORM")]
```

This is what I have done.

I was using the sapply to change all the names in that EVTYPE list but my interest is just changing the name of the levels and nothing else and keep the same dataframe.

#### Problem

The output is a dataframe of one variable only, EVTYPE.And I dont know why.

#### Expectations

I am honest all the examples from gsub I have seen, seems that it would be an easy operation, because it just changes strings, so I don't understand why it does not work.

Can someone help or suggest something else?

Comment: Sorry for that. It was just in case someone would like to replicate. The origin of the data is not the issue. It is NASA weather data that has lower and upper letters to identify the same event, but I cant seem to be able to replace the strings and keep a data frame when I use gsub

Comment: we do want to replicate, but you need to put in the effort to prepare something here without the need for us to download from some unknown 3rd party site

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use `sapply` here since `gsub` is "vectorized" and you already have your regular expression formatted with `|`'s. Something like this should work for condensing all of those labels to "WINTER STORM":

```
storm1$EVTYPES <- gsub(pattern="^WINTER STORM$|^WINTER STORM/HIGH WINDS$|^WINTER STORM HIGH WINDS$|^WINTER STORM/HIGH WIND$|^HEAVY SNOW/WINTER STORM$|^BLIZZARD/WINTER STORM$|^WINTER STORMS$","WINTER STORM",
                       replacement = "WINTER STORM",
                       x = storm1$EVTYPES)
```